# Flutter textfield behaves strange (updating with the wrong value)

Tags: flutter, flutter-text, flutter-textinputfield, flutter-textformfield, flutter-debug

I ran into a weird behavior related to the TextFormField, so I maintained a list of Objects in the parent widget, I'm using the following code to render a list of child widgets

```
 children: <Widget>[
                        ...childProfiles
                            .map((e) => ChildProfileCard(
                                childProfile: e,
                                removeChildProfile: removeChildProfile))
                            .toList(),
```

And the ChildProfileCard includes a TextFormField, the code is like the following

```
TextFormField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                          hintText: "Enter child's name",
                        ),
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Name is required';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
```

There is a "remove" function that simply removes one of the items from the list like the following

```
setState(() {
      childProfiles = childProfiles
          .where((childProfile) => childProfile.id != childProfileToRemove.id)
          .toList();
    });
```

When there are more than two items (two child widgets), I input some texts in the TextFormField in the first child widgets, then I remove the first item, the text will always automatically apply to the second child widget, what did I do wrong? I can confirm the list is correctly updated, but the text behaves strangely.

Before deleting, you can see we have different texts for different widgets
[image: Before deleting, you can see we have different texts for different widgets]

After deleting, the first widget's text is wrongfully copied over to the next widget, you can see the uuid is the second widget's.
[image: After deleting, the first widget's text is wrongfully copied over to the next widget]

Answer (score 0):

You should Use any unique key while building ChildProfileCard

```
ChildProfileCard(key: Key(<ANY UNIQUE VALUE>),)
```

Example

```
ChildProfileCard(key: Key(e.id),)
```